# Allocate each five elements of an array to a block

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have 15 elements in an array and I want to allocate each five of them to a block respectively. The elements are:

```
elements=["a",'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
```

I wanted to say first 5 elements are belonged to block#1, second five are belonged to block#2 and so on. I need to do it in a loop structure as later on, I need to use the information of each block for a special task. As I am new to python I don't know how to write it. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You know the elements in advance? Why don't you group them together hardcoded?

Comment: Yes , I knew these elements in advance, I read it from an excel file.I can't hardcode them because in reality they are 1500 elements and therefore I would have 300 blocks. I wrote 15 here, because if I learn how to write it in a loop for 15 elements I can dot it for 1500 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use list comprehension for that:

```
result = [elements[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(elements),5)]
```

which will generate:

```
>>> result
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']]
```

Or more generic:

```
def blockify(elements,n=5):
    return [elements[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(elements),n)]
```

and then call it with `blockify(elements,5)`.

What we do is we create a `range` that ranges from `0` to the `len(elements)` (length of the `elements`), and makes hops of `5` (or `n` in the generic case). Now for each of these steps, we add a slice `elements[i:i+5]` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all and divide index by 5 (floor division operator //) 
The result of dividing is number of group.